# How do I post a photo on a Facebook wall?

Tags: facebook

How do I post a photo on a Facebook wall?  I see I can upload a photo but that goes into the Photos area and doesn't show up on the wall itself.

Comment: Why are there no good answers to this question. I just uploaded a whole album, but no one can see them on their timelines or mine

Answer (score 1):

Click the 'Photo' button above the wall and select 'Upload photo/video'. As for viewing, the user may have set his/her settings on the Wall photos album so that only he/she can view them.

Answer (score 0):

If you go onto someone's wall, hit "upload a photo"; it will appear on their wall.

Comment: have you tried this? Do you have an example or some steps?